# pagination issue - multiple datatable on same page

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have multiple datatables on a page with server side rendering. They load fine initially but when I click on the pagination links on any of the table then the post params in ajax request are always from the last datatable. Here's my code.

Not really sure what's going on here. And the fact that initial requests are fine is further confusing the things for me.

```
for (i_dash = 1; i_dash <= count; i_dash++){
    var table = document.getElementById("dtBasicExample-"+i_dash);

    var encoded_query = tablelist.getAttribute("data-sql-query");
    var sql_query = unescape(encoded_query);
    var limit_arr = [15, 25, 50, 100];

    $('#dtBasicExample-'+i_dash).dataTable({

        "lengthMenu": limit_arr,
        dom: 'lBfrtip',
        serverSide: true,
        colReorder: false,
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bFilter":false,
        "bSort": false,

        "ajax": {
            // "url":'/paginate-dashboard',
            "url":'/algorithm/api/get_result',
            "type": "POST",
            "cache":false,
             "data"   : function( d) {
                d.query = sql_query;
            },

            complete: function(){
            },   
        }    
    });
}
```

Comment: The fact that you are passing SQL query to the backend is a HUGE security problem, you must rethink your code. Besides, unless I misunderstood you're sending the same query to all tables from `tablelist.getAttribute("data-sql-query")`, no wonder POST parameter is the same.

Comment: sorry for the confusion. it's not really a sql query, its a reference to saved sql query so security is fine. and if you notice tablelist variable is set inside of loop and it reference to a different div in loop so it's different every time.